# Keep characters between collations

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im using SQL Server 2012. I have an issue where I have one database that uses Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS.

I have some Polish characters(and in the future many other languages) that shows up differently.

For example if have these characters:

żśąółćęźę

It shows up like this in the database:

zsaólceze

The problem is that I can't change the collation(long story, but shortly due to compatibility issues).

I have a column named Address2 (varchar) in Customers table.

In my update statement i tried:

```
UPDATE Customers SET ADDRESS = N'żśąółćęźę'  WHERE customerid = 'mycustomerID'
```

It still shows the incorrect output even if I use N between the value.

I have tried to create another column with data type Nvarchar and that seems to work perfectly. But I want to avoid this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can't. Collations affect not only comparing and sorting strings, but also the way characters are stored, as you have found out yourself. The only option is to create another column with proper collation or change datatype to `nvarchar`.

See this sample:

```
create database ct collate Polish_CI_AS;
go
use ct;
go

-- any difference here?
select cast('żśąółćęźę' as varbinary)
use master;
go
select cast('żśąółćęźę' as varbinary)
go

use ct;
declare @t table 
(c1 varchar(1000) collate Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS, c2 nvarchar(1000) collate Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS,
c3 varchar(1000) collate Polish_CI_AS, c4 nvarchar(1000) collate Polish_CI_AS)

insert @t
values ('żśąółćęźę', 'żśąółćęźę', 'żśąółćęźę', 'żśąółćęźę')

select * from @t
```

Comment: So the only options is to change the column to NVARCHAR?

Comment: I've heard it should be possible to use ASCII values returned from the characters combined with COLLATE [COllationNAME].. Do you know anything about this?

Comment: Seems not be working:
Got this output:
zsaólceze zsaólceze zsaólceze zsaólceze

All the same?

Comment: The literals are interpreted differently (according to current database collation). See the update.

Comment: There is a difference. I've also tried this by creating a database with Polish Collation and the characters shows up fine. I thought I could use SELECT ASCII('ż') to get the ASCII value and then use that in the other tabel with a different collation - no luck. The ASCII values a completely different based on collation.

Comment: But thanks a lot for your sample and clarification. I already thought it wasn't possible and you confirmed that. Have a Nice day.